# How to put large png on screen

Tags: android

So right now im mkaing a game(android) and ive got a couple questions. Okay so whenever i draw on the screen any image that is not 320x480 it will fill only a section of the screen, for example if a draw a image that is 500x500 it will only show the top left part of the image, and if i draw a 32x32 it will fill only a part of the screen. This is a problem though because in order to get a sharp image i need the image to be larger in terms of pixels or else the image comes out pixelated. Basically is there a way to compress a large image into a set area, make a 500x500 image fit into 320x480 area without it cutting the image.

Answer (score 1):

Usually loading scaled down version of Bitmap files is preferred as shown [here in Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html), using a scale option.

However from your question, I presume you'd like to read just a rectangular part of the image file. Luckily, there is a class [`BitmapRegionDecoder`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapRegionDecoder.html)
 which does just that:

```
BitmapRegionDecoder brd = BitmapRegionDecoder.newInstance(<file_name>,true);

Bitmap b = brd.decodeRegion(new Rect(0,0,32,32), BitmapFactory.Options());
//-- In the Options object above, you can set scale, 
//-- which will read scaled down region and do it so faster--

//-- after you no longer need above resources anywhere, remember to free them --
brd.recycle();
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the following size images in the folders:

```
Hdpi: 480*800
Ldpi: 320*460
mdpi: 720*960
xdpi: 800*1280
```